# Convert Hexadecimal string to long python

Tags: python, struct, hex, long-integer, endianness

I want to get the value of 99997 in big endian which is (2642804992) and then return the answer as a long value

here is my code in python:

```
v = 99997
ttm = pack('>i', v) # change the integer to big endian form 
print ("%x"), {ttm}
r = long(ttm, 16) # convert to long (ERROR)
return r
```

> Output: **%x set(['\x00\x01\x86\x9d'])**
>
> Error: **invalid literal for long() with base 16: '\x00\x01\x86\x9d'**

As the string is already in hex form why isn't it converting to a long? How would I remove this error and what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: What do you expect the value of `r` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pack** will return a string representation of the data you provide.

The string representation is different than a **base 16** of a long number. Notice the **\x** before each number.

Edit:

try this

```
ttm = pack('>I',v)
final, = unpack('<I',ttm)
print ttm
```

Notice the use of **I**, this so the number is treated as an unsigned value

Comment: so how would i convert this string of bytes into a long value?

Comment: you can use struct.unpack, just like @uphill suggested. You can change the formatting, use '<i' and this will turn into a conversion from bigendian to little endian

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `struct.unpack` as a reverse operation to `struct.pack`.

```
r, = unpack('<i', ttm)
```

this will `r` set to `-1652162304`.

Answer (score 0):

You just converted the integer value to big endian binary bytes.

This is useful mostly to embed in messages addressed to big-endian machines (PowerPC, M68K,...)

Converting to `long` like this means parsing the `ttm` string which should be `0x1869D` as ASCII.
(and the print statement does not work either BTW)

If I just follow your question title: "Convert hexadecimal string to long":

just use `long("0x1869D",16)`. No need to serialize it.
(BTW `long` only works in python 2. In python 3, you would have to use `int` since all numbers are represented in the `long` form)

Well, I'm answering to explain why it's bound to fail, but I'll edit my answer when I really know what you want to do.

Comment: That's weird: the answers are downvoted when they're explaining something useful and the question is upvoted (well, not anymore :)) when it's not clear!

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the downvotes. Both current answers seem correct to me; upvoting. Couldn't have been the OP, since he doesn't have enough rep to downvote.

Comment: @Andrew Cheong: yes, not the OP! Sometimes we should refrain from answering such unclear questions, even if we know why the OP is struggling with the different concepts. That's a like a rep trap. thanks BTW

Comment: True, but also those new to the community don't necessarily know how to ask clear questions. In any case, it wasn't the OP who downvoted (in case that was your implication).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i wanted to get the value of 99997 in big endian which is (2642804992) and then return the answer as a long value.

Comment: aaaah it's clearer now: then please update your post because 1) there are 3 answers that don't really answer your question and 2) I'll be able to remove my downvote (and maybe my answer too). Only Radu Dita got what you wanted. You should accept it, end of story :)

Comment: @Andrew Cheong: yeah I know it was not the OP who downvoted. I don't mind a downvote every now and them to teach me I'm not omniscient, but at least I need an explanation so I do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice question.

Here is what you are looking for.

```
s = str(ttm)
for ch in r"\bx'":
    s = s.replace(ch, '')

print(int(s, 16))
```

The problem is that `ttm` is similar to a string in some aspects. This is what is looks like: `b'\x00\x01\x86\x9d'`. Supplying it to `int` (or `long`) keeps all the non-hex characters. I removed them and then it worked.

After removing the non-hex-digit chars, you are left with `0001869d` which is indeed `99997`

**Comment**  I tried it on Python 3. But on Python 2 it will be almost the same, you won't have the `b` attached to the string, but otherwise it's the same thing.

Comment: i tried s = str(ttm) but it gave an arror that utf-8 cannot encode convert a byte 0x9d.